# How do I get subdomains to work on my local machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cloned a repo and am trying to get it to work. The app is very heavily dependent on subdomains. For example, signin.app.com or company1.app.com.

However, since I am trying to get it to run on my local machine, I can't simply do signin.localhost:3000

So, how do I get these subdomains to work using localhost?

Thanks!

Comment: you can do SUBDOMAIN.lvh.me:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gene said,

/etc/hosts file:- (add)

> 127.0.0.1  subdomain1.localhost

And on Rails3 this is treated as a domain, so you need to just add this:

> 127.0.0.1  subdomain1.localhost.local

then try, 
http://subdomain1.localhost:PORT

Answer (score 1):

In linux

open command prompt
 `>sudo  vi /etc/hosts`

Add a line in file

`127.0.0.1 subdomain.hostname.com`

and press `Esc` and `:wq` (means save host file)

thats it you type  `subdomain.hostname.com` in your browser. Subdomain will run in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the domain names to your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29), routing them to localhost.